# Appending action to the last appended row using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to send data to server and update the current page with no reloading. I have this script:

```
$.ajax
        ({
            url: 'insert.php', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data: {data1: emp, data2: pos, data3: sal},
            dataType: "json", 

            success:function(data)
            {
                    var emp_n = data.emp_name;
                    var btn = '<button type="Button" id="del" name="del" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>';
                    $("#before_tr").before("<tr><td>"+data.emp_name+"</td><td>"+data.position+"</td><td>"+data.salary+"</td><td>"+btn+"</td></tr>");

            },
```

As you see, I have a delete button that should be added too to the same row. But this button won't be active until I refresh the page. What I want is to append action like this PHP Based code for a delete button of each row:

```
<tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                    <td contenteditable><?php echo $row['emp_name'] ?></td>
                    <td contenteditable><?php echo $row['position'] ?></td>
                    <td contenteditable><?php echo $row['salary'] ?></td>
                    <td><button type="Button" id="del" name="del" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
```

What I've tried is the following:

```
$.ajax
        ({
            url: 'insert_with_ajax.php', //Sending variable emp, pos, and sal, into this url
            type: 'POST', //I will get variable and use them inside my PHP code using $_POST['emp']
            data: {data1: emp, data2: pos, data3: sal},//Now we can use $_POST[data1];
            dataType: "json", //JSON or HTML

            success:function(arr)
            {
                //if(data=="success")
                //{
                    //alert("Data added");
                    var emp_n = arr.emp_name;
                    var btn = '<a href="delete_id.php?id="'+emp_n+'><button type="Button" id="del" name="del" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>';
                    $("#before_tr").before("<tr><td>"+arr.emp_name+"</td><td>"+arr.position+"</td><td>"+arr.salary+"</td><td>"+btn+"</td></tr>");
                    $("#emp_name").val("");
                    $("#position").val("");
                    $("#salary").val("");
                //}
            },
```

Where I added this line `<a href="delete_id.php?id="'+emp_n+'` to the following:

```
var btn = '<a href="delete_id.php?id="'+emp_n+'><button type="Button" id="del" name="del" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>';
```

When I click on delete button of the last one added using AJAX the page go to delete_id but the link is like this:

```
delete_id.php?id=
```

id is equal to empty.

So, What I am working on is like when we add a status on Facebook and you delete it directly with no need for reloading the page. I am trying and I hope that someone could help.

Comment: And what is in `insert_with_ajax.php`?

Comment: it is a PHP code where we send data to server and encode them into JSON and send them to AJAX so we append them to the table. I think If someone could connect to my computer using teamviewer will understand what I am suffering

Comment: `insert_with_ajax.php` returns some data `arr` from which you take `arr.emp_name`. Have you checked what is returned from it? `console.log(arr);`

Comment: Yeah it is just a mistake sorry, but still won't work.

Comment: I said - check the value of `arr`. What is it?

Comment: At the console log I see the value of arr, but it still empty in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code once again:

```
'<a href="delete_id.php?id="'+emp_n+'>' 
                           ^ - see? you have a closing " here.
```

This means that no values will be added to your `href` attribute as it's already closed.

Proper code is:

```
'<a href="delete_id.php?id='+emp_n+'">'
                                    ^ -see? closing " moved after emp_n
```